# How do I replace new line and space with <td><tr> using sed for every calendar month?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I use this code but it only works for January. How can I use `sed` to work for every month?

```
var='<table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">'
cal -h | sed '1{s|^|'"${var}"'|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|' >> file.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `for` loop to go over the months needed, for 1–12 that's:

```bsh
var='<table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">'
for i in {1..12}; do
  cal -hm$i | sed '1{s|^|'"${var}"'|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|' >>file.html
done
```

This works in 16.04. As pointed out by others in the comments and confirmed by [the `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/cal.1.html), in 17.10 (et seqq.) `cal` doesn't have the `-h` option any more. You can use `ncal` instead, see `man cal` for details.

Comment: I don't know what version of `cal` you are both using, but `cal -h` as well as `cal -hm1` give me a "Usage:" summary. However `ncal -h` and `ncal -hm1` work. (I'm using 17.10)